# SUMPRODUCT to get row +1

Tags: excel, row

I have a table like below:

```
12/7/2012   A   B   
                     100    

12/21/2012  A   I   
                     20

12/23/2012  A   I   
                     25     

12/1/2013   A   I   
                     20     

12/1/2014   A   I   
                     20
```

I want to get the value in column D where column B is "A" and column C is "I". I used a sumproduct to get the value in column D, but I need to go down 1 row from wherever column B is "A" and column C is "I". This is my formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B="A"),--(C:C="I"),F:F+1).
```

It should return a value of 85, but it returns a value of 4.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
=SUM((B1:B10="A")*(C1:C10="I")*(D2:D11))
```

as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B10="A"),--(C1:C10="I"),(D2:D11))
```

and extend the range as far as you need to.

What happens with your formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B="A"),--(C:C="I"),D:D+1)
```

is that it is just adding one to each row in column D. D1, D3, D5 and D7 are empty cells so count as zero. So for the four matching rows it is adding one to the total and the result is 4.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B="A"),--(C:C="I"),D:D+1) this worked. - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B="A"),--(C:C="I"),D:D+1)` worked it may just be coincidence. You might check by taking a copy and in that deleting D1 with Shift cells up then applying:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,"A",C:C,"I")
```

Or of you don't have SUMIFS filter to delete rows that do not contain a date in ColumnA, `A` in ColumnB and `I` in ColumnC, then summing ColumnD.

With SUMIFS an alternative to @Tom's SUMPRODUCT might be:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D1000001,B1:B1000000,"A",C1:C1000000,"I")
```