# SumProduct, Left, and Offset sumrange by -1 Row, 1 column

Tags: excel, offset, sumproduct

I am trying to create a formula that will search column A for West* (aka LEFT(A:A,4)="West" ) and sum the corresponding number that is stored one row up and one column right.

Other criteria:

- Must be able to sum numbers stored as text
- must be able to reference a closed workbook without "breaking" (ie- no sumif(s), count(a,if(s)))
- must work with blank rows in "sumrange" column
- ideally no array formulas

This works if the data is stored in the same row as "West"; I've played around with an offset formula in the sumrange to no avail

```
SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A3:A100,4)="West"),--(B3:B100))
```

I've also tried: 
`SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A:A,4)="West"),(B:B-1))` based on
[SUMPRODUCT to get row +1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936369/sumproduct-to-get-row-1)

[image: Data Example]

Comment: Change the `B3:B100` to `B2:B99`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to OFFSET, just use an offset range, i.e. shift the 2nd range up one row to `B2:B99`.

```
SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A3:A100,4)="West"),--(B2:B99))
```